# Is there a way to register for WLan notifications using C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++-winrt

I am porting a Win32 application into WinRT using C++/WinRT.

Currently my Win32 application uses APIs **WlanRegisterNotification** and **WlanNotificationCallback** to get notified when a user connects to a WiFi router.

How can I achieve the same functionality using C++/WinRT ?

Answer (score 0):

Not my area of expertise, but I believe the NetworkInformation::NetworkStatusChanged event should suit your needs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh700376%28v%3dwin.10%29

For most usage, it should give you similar information. The examples are in javascript, but should translate 1:1 to C++ WinRT in terms of types & namespaces. See also here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation

Thanks,

Ben (MSFT)